# Manage dataset nullable column in gridview item template

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I create a data set from XML document. In my first example return the dataset like this

```
FLD_ID  FLD_VALUE
1       1000
```

So i easily assign this data set to Grid view.But in second example return the dataset like this

```
FLD_ID
1
```

Now i assign this data set to same grid view means it return the error message. FLD_VAL doesn't contain the current context.

I want to manage this in item template section. Please help me to fix this issue..

Example 1:

```
-root-

-FLD_ID- "1" -FLD_ID-

-FLD_VALUE- "1000" -FLD_VALUE-

-root-
```

Example 2:

```
-root-

-FLD_ID- "2" -FLD_ID-

-FLD_VALUE- "" -FLD_VALUE-

-root-
```

Comment: Make that second xml element to pass empty string value or check if the FLD_VALUE is null or not,If it is null,bind the string empty value to that field.

Comment: I fixed this issue. I was create the empty column in data set.My problem is solved. Thanks for your reply.